# Completed orders on Woocommerce don't send e-mail message to customer

Tags: email, woocommerce

I do not get any e-mails after the order is completed. I have read through many support threads and tried to fix it by myself but it does not work. I have even tested with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/ – I get messages with or without a specified server.

I don’t know if it makes any difference but I copied the template file for this email message and changed the message to:

```
<p><?php printf( __( 'Hej! Din beställning på %s har blivit slutbehandlat.</br></br> Tusen tack och tusen grattis till att du köpt utbildningen Tänk dig fri! Detta är en av de viktigaste investeringarna i dig själv som du kan göra. Jag hoppas att utbildningen kommer ge dig allt det du längtar efter!<br/><br/><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIsx6hj_I-I&feature=youtu.be&hd=1" target="_blank">Här är en länk till ett videoklipp jag vill att du kollar på</a> innan du börjar studera kapitel 1.<br/><br/>Ljudfilerna till boken <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nn3zxo50n4aogqn/AABLjM43eiv2JtG3mPQ5qIOWa?dl=0" target="_blank">finner du här.</a><br/><br/>Tänk dig fri boken skickas vanligen till dig inom 2-5 arbetsdagar. Dina beställningsdetaljer finns längst ner i detta meddelande.<br/><br/>Många varma lyckönskningar,<br/>Susanna<br/><br/>', 'woocommerce' ), get_option( 'blogname' ) ); ?></p>
```

This template is on my child-theme folder inside of woocommerce/emails. For what matters I – as a customer – have never received any message and yes, I have checked my spam box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! The issue was being caused by the fact that the woocommerce e-mail sender had an email address that did not match with the domain. I changed the e-mail address and now everything works perfectly.

Hope this might help anyone else!